# How to setup Typescript for Ionic v2 in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, ionic-framework

Ionic has recently upgraded to version 2 which is well-supported with TypeScript. 
I'm now using IntelliJ IDEA to work with it, but don't know how to setup TypeScript to work with them.

So, how to set-up the ionic project in version 2 to work with TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest ionic@beta you can do `ionic start myapp --v2 --ts` to download the Typescript version of the starter.